# WordPress - Disable WP postrating on all pages except post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using following code of wp postrating plugin on my all pages

```
if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
```

I do not want to allow users to rate on all pages except post page. I checked documentation faq and plugin author's forum page but I haven't got any clue how to disable rating for users.

Any hint or clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: So don't execute the function anywhere else than the post page? Not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, if I am not clear. What I meant is I want to show rating but I do not want to allow users to rate except on post page

Comment: You'll really have to ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

By post page, do you mean the single post view page?

If so, then the easiest method would be to only include the call in you single.php template.